# Publisher - Subscriber communication

Tags: ros, communication, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

My implementation is the following:

1. I have created a node that subscribes to two topics (Listener node).
2. There are two more nodes each of which has one Publisher

I have noticed that if I run the Listener node first (using rosrun) and post the messages using ROS_INFO nothing is printed. This makes sense since the Publishers haven'r ran yet.
However, when I start the Publishers I still see nothing printed.
This is strange, since if I start the two Publisher nodes first and then the listener everything seems OK.

My question is:
Is there a specific sequence according to which the nodes should be started in order the Publishers and Subscribers to communicate correctly ?

Thank you

---

Update:

my package is called "nodes" containing nodes "complete_test1" and "FL_leg_control"

The complete_test1 node is an example from webots in order to communicate with the robot model.
The FL_leg_control is a node I have build in order to calculate the torques needed to drive the robot's legs.

The FL_leg_control nodes publishes in the "FL_command_dispatch" topic and subscribes in the "FL_encoders_feedback" topic.
The complete_test1 node publishes in the "FL_encoders_feedback" topic and subscribes in the "FL_command_dispatch" topic.

The messages are:

1. LegEncoders
2. LegCommand

and as you can see they are included in the nodes using:

```
#include "nodes/LegEncoders.h"
#include "nodes/LegCommand.h"
```

I am sending you (with the following google drive link bellow) the code for these two nodes and the two message types I have created in the "msg" folder.

If you have any problems reading them, please tell me.
Thank you in advance

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-K_xoRxXFeUfkl4ZFlxdlZhTlc0UDZqcVlxUmRGVFZNR1hiTkl2M1RxaTZGZThxYng2bGc&usp=sharing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213421/publisher---subscriber-communication/) by [Thanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/23133/thanasis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-07-10**:
Are all of these nodes running on the same computer?

**Comment by [Thanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/23133/thanasis/) on 2015-07-11**:
Yes, they are running on the same computer

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-07-12**:
The sequence *shouldn't* matter. But I cannot say for sure unless you post some of the code... What kind of messages are these?

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-12**:
You should post your code, maybe you forgot something... like ros::Spin or you always create a new publisher when you publish or something else like that.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-07-14**:
Phew... That's a lot of code. I will be able to look through it later tonight. I'll let you know if I see something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you very much for you help.
It is a lot of code but
the complete_test1 node is based on a node provided by Cyberbotics Webots with the same name (complete_test).
What I have added are the topics, the publishers, the subscribers, the callbacks and the message types.
Maybe you can check only these parts...

Thank you for your time.

---

Originally posted by [Thanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/23133/thanasis/) with karma: 16 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0